# Zend Framework console application

Tags: zend-framework2, php

I've followed the steps to create a Zend Framework 2 application from the skeleton ( http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html )

There also is a very nice tutorial for the ZF2 native console support available
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.console.introduction.html

Now the tutorial says:

> Let’s assume that we’d like our application to handle the following
>   command line:

```
> zf user resetpassword user@mail.com
```

> When a user runs our application (zf) with these parameters, we’d like
>   to call action resetpassword of Application\IndexController.

Problem is that there is no description available on how to get the script running on CONSOLE ( currently windows ) - there's no zf or any other executable script in the created folder structure

Any hints?

ideally would be a bin folder in the application root directory which contains a entry-script for each application module

e.g. run a application module called module1

```
php appfolder/bin/module1.php --verbose
```

or

```
php appfolder/bin/cli.php module1 --verbose
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution.
Just like a web-based ZF2 application the entry point is the index.php in appfolder/public

The example app from the tutorial above is called this way

```
php.exe public\index.php user resetpassword user@mail.com
```

#### linux wrapper to call zf2 console apps

change into your ZF2 application folder

```
mkdir bin    
touch bin/app
chmod +x bin/app
```

put this into your app file

```
#!/bin/sh
PHP_BIN=`which php`
WDIR=`dirname ${0}"`
if test -x "${PHP_BIN}"; then
    cd "${WDIR}"
    "${PHP_BIN}" "../public/index.php" "${@}"
    exit "${?}"
fi
echo "php binary not found, please install php-cli"
exit 1;
```

Now you should be able to run your app this way

```
app user resetpassword user@mail.com
```

Comment: in linux you can use `app.php` where first line is shebang `#!/usr/bin/env php`. Then you just run it with `$ bin/app.php user resetpassword user@mail.com`

Answer (score 1):

For those interested... based on Michel Feldheim's answer I've improved it slightly to handle symlinks as well and it also does not matter where you run the script from as it will always find the correct location.  This one does however use bash"

```
#!/bin/bash
PHP_BIN=`which php`
SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ] ; do SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"; done
scriptDir="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
rootDir="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$scriptDir/../../../../" )" && pwd )"
if test -x "${PHP_BIN}"; then
    cd $rootDir
    "${PHP_BIN}" "public/index.php" "${@}"
    exit "${?}"
fi
echo "php binary not found, please install php-cli"
exit 1;
```

In above example, $scriptDir is where the actual script you are running resides.  And rootDir should be the base directory of your application.  So lets assume the application lives under /data/www/someapplication  and this application contains a modules/Application/bin folder with the filename run.  From linux path (/) running:

```
sh /data/www/someapplication/modules/Application/bin/run
```

Would change directory into /data/www/someapplication, and then run:

```
php public/index.php <your arguments>
```

Answer (score -1):

A command line tool used to be shipped with ZF1 versions. Probably the tutorial is referring to that.